# Java - Searching an array only yields first match and not all matches

Tags: java, arrays

```
    String searchValue;     
    boolean found = false;
    int index = 0;

    System.out.println("Enter a name to search for in the array.");
    searchValue = kb.nextLine();

    while (found == false && index < names.length) {
        if (names[index].indexOf(searchValue) != -1) {
            found = true;
        } else {
            index++;
        }
    }
    if (found) {
        System.out.println("That name matches the following element:");
        System.out.println(names[index]);
    } else {
        System.out.println("That name was not found in the array.");
    }
```

Like the title says, this only yields the first match and not all the matches in the array.  How would I change it so that it shows all matches?

Comment: Because once a match is found, the variable is set to true and the while condition fails thereby skipping remaining matches

Answer (score 0):

Remove this part and think about the whole algorithm in general. You have to re factor it.

```
if(names[index].indexOf(searchValue) != -1)
{
    found = true;
}
```

The reason that it gives you only the first one is that you set the found to true and Java won't go in the While loop after that.

Comment: I get that, but I don't understand how to identify a match without changing found to true.  Should I reset found to false after the if statement?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of terminating the loop by setting the found flag to true you should instead add the finding to a second array which holds all the matches and continue on to the next iteration until you reached the end.

Answer (score 0):

You're exiting your loop after the first match is found - how about this:

```
    while (index < names.length) {
        if (names[index].indexOf(searchValue) != -1) {
            System.out.println("That name matches the following element:");
            System.out.println(names[index]);
            found = true;
        } else {
            index++;
        }
    }

    if (!found) {
        System.out.println("That name was not found in the array.");
    }
```